# Copying 1 dimension of a 2-dimensional array to another part of the same array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am new to C++.

Given a 2-dimensional array defined as:

```
boolean myArray[3][8];
```

and I want to **shuffle** the cells around in the first dimension elements around so that, say, `myArray[2][........]` is copied to `myArray[2][........]`.

I would normally *iterate* through the array with a *nested loop* that copies each cell. Is there a better way to do this?  In other words, is there a way to copy a single dimension of a two dimensional array to another part of that that array with a single command of some sort?

Comment: `boy I hope I haven't made this unintelligible` - well, maybe if your source and target weren't identical...

Comment: You could do something like `memcpy(myArray[0], myArray[2], 8);` to copy from 1 to the other. That the kind of thing you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[In this example](http://ideone.com/KY6RQi) the program declares the following 2D **int** array (instead of bool):

```
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16
```

and demonstrates how to switch the data between the first and last indexes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
    int myArray[3][8] =
    {
      { 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17 },
      { 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 },
      { 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16 }
    };

    // Copy data from index 2 to index 0
    int bkup[8] = { 0 };
    memcpy(bkup, myArray[0], sizeof(myArray[0]));
    memcpy(myArray[0], myArray[2], sizeof(myArray[2]));
    memcpy(myArray[2], bkup, sizeof(bkup));

    // Print array content to the screen
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            printf("%d ", myArray[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }      

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17
```

Comment: Just change the data type of the array to **bool** and initialize it with `true` or `false` and you will be good to go.

Comment: Since C++11, you may directly do `std::swap(myArray[0], myArray[2]);`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I new there would be a way.  this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
memmove(&myArray[2], &myArray[2][2], 4);
```

To copy some of the bytes from the 2nd array to the beginning of itself.

Comment: If you need it for overlapping memory such as in the 2nd "don't do this" part, I think you might be best off sticking with a loop and doing it manually -- that way you ensure memory integrity.

Comment: memmove(&myArray[2], &myArray[2][2], 4 * sizeof(boolean)) to the rescue!

Comment: @FRob good call, I've never seen `memmove` before, but looks like it's there exactly for this purpose. I edited my answer to reflect using this instead.